# Tips for insulation above unvented bay window roof

Tags: attic, roofing

I have a portion of my kitchen under its own roof similar to a bay window. This piece of roofing is unventilated. There is paper-faced fiberglass batt insulation in the cavity with a vertical vapor barrier to separate the cavity from the rest of the home, however this cavity extends a couple feet into the kitchen and it definitely is still a bit drafty.

I want to be careful not to promote moisture issues, but is there an insulation that is safe to come in contact with that roof sheathing without causing mold or rot issues? My initial thought was to try rockwool right against the sheathing then add a vapor barrier then finish with any other insulation. Thoughts?

[image: here]

[image: here]

Comment: What makes you think contact with roof sheathing is a problem? Lack of _ventilation_ may be a problem. Beyond that it doesn't much matter.